# Как сместить центр спрайта в Unity3d?

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

Как сместить центр спрайта в сторону, что бы при изменение Rotation в поле Z
спрайт поворачивался по смещённой оси?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках спрайта (картинки а не Sprite Renderer) есть параметр `Pivot` также известный как `Ancore Point`. По мимо стандартных `left-right-center-bottom-top` можно указать кастумный вариант. Но смещён будет не только поворот, но и позиция.